Tune Least Squares Support Vector Machine (LS-SVM) With Grid Search Optimization
I am looking for LSSVM with Gride Search optimization in Python, but could not find it.
Scikit learn has SVM with Grid Search but not for LSSVM.

Do you mean Grid Search Optimization? https://dannyvanpoucke.be/building-scikit-learn-regressor-lssvm-en/

Could you share more about the data and your objective?

If you follow @JuhaP's link, then you have a SciKit Learn compatible implementation:
class LSSVMRegression(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
  """
  An Least Squared Support Vector Machine (LS-SVM) regression class
  Attributes:
  - gamma : the hyper-parameter (float)
  - kernel: the kernel used (string: rbf, poly, lin)
  - kernel_: the actual kernel function
  - x : the data on which the LSSVM is trained (call it support vectors)
  - y : the targets for the training data
  - coef_ : coefficents of the support vectors
  - intercept_ : intercept term
  """
  def __init__(self, gamma:float=1.0, kernel:str=None, c:float=1.0, d:float=2, sigma:float=1.0):
    self.gamma=gamma
    self.c=c
    self.d=d
    self.sigma=sigma
    if (kernel is None):
      self.kernel='rbf'
    else:
      self.kernel=kernel
    params=dict()
    if (kernel=='poly'):
      params['c']=c
      params['d']=d
    elif (kernel=='rbf'):
      params['sigma']=sigma
    self.kernel_=LSSVMRegression.__set_kernel(self.kernel,**params)
    self.x=None
    self.y=None
    self.coef_=None
    self.intercept_=None

  def fit(self,X:np.ndarray,y:np.ndarray):
    self.x=X
    self.y=y
    Omega=self.kernel_(self.x,self.x)
    Ones=np.array([[1]]*len(self.y)) 
 
    A_dag = np.linalg.pinv(np.block([
          [0, Ones.T ],
          [Ones, Omega + self.gamma**-1 * np.identity(len(self.y))]
          ])) 
    B = np.concatenate((np.array([0]),self.y), axis=None)
 
    solution = np.dot(A_dag, B)
    self.intercept_ = solution[0]
    self.coef_ = solution[1:]

  def predict(self,X:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
    Ker = self.kernel_(X,self.x)
    Y=np.dot(self.coef_,Ker.T) +self.intercept_
    return Y

Now you may use SciKit Learn's built in Grid Search as implemented in GridSearchCV.
Credit: Danny E. P. Vanpoucke - Building your own SciKit Learn Regressor Class: LS-SVM (GitHub Repository).

This code can not be used for  classification !!!!

@novin, LS SVM is for Regression not for classification. For classification you should use the regular SVM.
